# What means "Non-inline to improve code quality as uncommon path"

Tags: c#, arrays

I was looking at source code of List and LargeArrayBuilder classes in .net core 3.0 and saw that method AddWithBufferAllocation marked by comment "Non-inline to improve code quality as uncommon path". Also, method has attribute `MethodImpl` with value `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining`. How does noinlining improve code quality?

I believe this degrades performance. I could be wrong, but the call method is the overhead of physically calling a method (call instruction) and passing parameters. Especially, if we use to value type.

[sources](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Collections/Generic/LargeArrayBuilder.SpeedOpt.cs,099b00015672dccc,references)

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify your claim that "This step degraded performance."?

Comment: I could be wrong, but the call method is the overhead of physically calling a method (call instruction) and passing parameters. Especially, if we use to value type @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: Thanks. I've inlined your comment into the question to clarify that "degrades performance" is your personal (not validated by any measurements for this particular case) opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It improves performance in the *general* case when that `if` test is false and it doesn't make the method call at all.

It means that `AddRange`, that *might* make the method call (but rarely) is smaller and can be better optimised than the same method with, potentially, all of `AddWithBufferAllocation` inlined inside it.